# Check varchar2 cointains CHR(10) at the end

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need a CSV with lot of line. I need to check if every line has CHR(10) at the end.
I tried:

```
IF (SUBSTR(line, -2) == CHR(10)) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THERE IS!');
END IF;
```

But doesn't work!
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: hi. substr -2 gives you two characters, use -1 if you only want the last one. see `select substr('Text',-2) from dual;` ==> `xt`

Answer (score 4):

You must use -1, not -2 as second argument for substr:
this example works perfectly.

moreover... equality comparison is "=", not "==".

```
declare
    test_string varchar2(100) := 'text ending with newiline'||chr(10);
begin
   IF (SUBSTR(test_string, -1) = CHR(10)) THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THERE IS!');
   END IF;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `REGEXP_INSTR` to specifically check the final character:

```
IF (REGEXP_INSTR(line, CHR(10) || '$') > 0) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THERE IS!');
END IF;
```